# Quadratic model - how to test

Tags: polynomial, contrasts, quadratic-form

For my research I have a hypothesis containing a categorical IV (positive vs negative article that the participants have to read) and a continuous moderator (ideology level of the participant).

The x axis is the evaluation that participants are giving (by answering different questions on a Likert 7-point-scale). On this following graph, you can see the interaction I'm suspecting.

[image]

So I have a quadratic effect of attitude, and someone on here told me to use this model:

$$DV=\beta_0+\beta_1 ideology+\beta_2 ideology^2 + \beta_3article + \beta_4article*ideology + \beta_5article*ideology^2 + \epsilon$$

So far, everything is clear.

However, I've never worked with quadratic interactions before, so I want to be sure I'm doing the right thing. So far, I've dummy coded the IV (article) and squared attitude. And I have put everything in a multiple regression model on SPSS.

Is there anything else I have to do? When reading about quadratic models, there were a lot of mentions of contrasts and polynomial terms. Is this something I have to worry about and include in my model, or is that only important when testing for simple effects?

Answer (score 1):

Your model is theoretically correct. The first 3 terms is for $article=0$ and the next 3 terms is for $article=1$.

I am not trained on contrasts and testing for simple effects, but what I can suggest is that you test for the significance of the quadratic term ($\beta_2$ and $\beta_5$).

You can do that via an F-test in `R`, using `anova()`.